# @media запрос исходя из ширины блока

Tags: css, адаптивная-верстка, less, media-queries

Можно ли как-то написать [`CSS`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css)-правила для блока исходя из его ширины?
То есть нужно смотреть не на ширину экрана,а на ширину блока:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {}
```

Как такое реализовать на [`CSS`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) или [`LESS`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/less)?

Comment: `media`-запросы не предназначены для этого

Comment: а есть другие способы это написать? Может быть без @media

Comment: Разве что с помощью `JS`, есть такая библиотека — https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries

Comment: `JS` не подходит